# How will EOS integrate with Steem Blog system?

Tags: untagged

Dan Larimer mentioned EOS would integrate with Steem blog system. How would that work and what is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1):

No specification was published about how it will work yet.

However, Steemit + Steem is fundamentally enabled by a particular set of features, including feeless transactions, high TPS, uncapped supply, observer auditability through on-chain operations, and a degree of censorship-resistance.

Due to the architectural similarities shared by EOSIO and STEEM, all these features can be natively used in EOSIO. Thus, a Steemit-like application may be implemented as its own EOSIO-based chain, as a side-chain to another EOSIO blockchain, or as a non-native token to an already existing EOSIO chain.

Answer (score 0):

EOS generalized the application specific features in Steemit and bitshares ,say account names , feeless. etc .
At user stand point it's just sidechain with native tokens.
At develpoer perspective its boon, developer can redirect for account creation to Eos dan project.just like Dtube ,Dmania,
busy did.